# mktime resulting in OverflowError: mktime argument out of range

Tags: python, python-datetime, pytz, mktime, python-docker

When attempting to get a time using mktime, I get a overflow exception. This occurs on a Debian docker image, but not on my host machine:

```
docker pull python:3.9.7
```

https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/python/3.9.7/images/sha256-9d7d2a6ce11fe5a12c74f81b860f5142fd91192427ece0b566c4fb962353325e?context=explore

pytz==2021.3

Here's a toy example:

```
import datetime
import time
import pytz

ts = 1655043357
tz = 'Canada/Eastern'

utc_time = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)

tz = pytz.timezone(tz)
tz_aware = datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz)

utc_ts = time.mktime(utc_time.timetuple()) # No exception

ts = time.mktime(tz_aware.timetuple()) # <----Results in exception
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/toy_example.py", line 15, in <module>
    time.mktime(tz_aware.timetuple())
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
```

There is no exception when running on my host machine and works as expected. Any idea why that's happening?

edit:
Interestingly, if I change my current system time to last week March 7, 2024 it works without an exception being raised

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? to get a Unix timestamp, datetime objects have a `timestamp` method, no need to use mktime. Also, your pytz version is totally outdated. You shouldn't be using pytz in the first place, we have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) since Python 3.9.

Comment: That's right, its an old pytz, but happens with latest one as well. I'm also aware of zoneinfo, but this is legacy code trying to root cause the issue. The fact is mktime works perfectly in some platforms but not on others.

Comment: `mktime` is a function from the platform's C library (look for time.h, Python basically just calls into that), that's why the results can be different on different platforms. So my suggestion would be to try to avoid that by using the datetime's method. Btw. pytz *does* get updates for recent changes in the IANA tz db, the latest version is 2024.1, but I noticed it lags behind the IANA updates these days.

Comment: If it works on the 7th March but stopped working on the 13th March, then it sounds like a locale problem. Is there a locale difference between the Docker instance and other test environments?

Comment: Hard to say; I would assume so, until convinced otherwise. I tried the code on a regular debian Linux machine and it works fine - although the result is actually nonsense; if you get different Unix times for the same instance in time, just in different time zones, something is wrong. The problem is that `mktime` isn't meant to handle time zones in the first place.

Comment: I believe the mktime in this scenario was trying to get the epoch time shifted to the local timezone.  So if there is a timezone difference of 1 hour from UTC timezone, mktime will return the  epoch time + 3600. This is how it was implemented in the codebase, definitely not saying this is correct way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the reason why changing the date fixed the exception. Those of us in North America have a daylight savings time that went into effect on March 10th 2024. This is why when setting a system time before March 10th, everything works. After daylight savings time went into effect, the exception starting occurring.

As part of timetuple(), there is a is_dst field that gets added ONLY when daylight savings time is in effect. When you pass this into mktime in older linux platforms (such as the docker image in the question), it will trigger an (very misleading) overflow exception. On newer platforms, it accepts is_dst (works on newer debian and osx).

The correct way is to avoid mktime altogether:

```
# current date and time
tz = 'Canada/Eastern'
tz = pytz.timezone(tz)

tz_aware = datetime.now(tz=tz)
ts = datetime.timestamp(tz_aware)

utc_time = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
utc_ts = datetime.timestamp(utc_time)
```